# emacsclient flashes already-open file for ~2s before showing target file

Tags: emacsclient

My `.emacs` file opens itself so that I can always switch buffers to quickly make changes. I do this with:

```
;; $HOME/.emacs
(find-file "~/.emacs")
```

I start emacs with `emacs --daemon` and open files from the command line with `emacsclient -c <FILE_NAME>`.

However, when I open those files, my (already open) `.emacs` file will flash for about two seconds before opening the file I actually care about.

How can I remove the two second "flash of my `.emacs` file" and instead make emacsclient immediately show the file I care about?

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Yep - a similar behavior seems to exist with `emacs -q --daemon`, then `emacsclient tmp.txt`. I get a flash of `*scratch*`, and after two seconds the screen switches to `tmp.txt`.